# Is there a way to check the default web browser that is set up on my smartphone?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I want to use "Chrome Custom Tab."

However, to use "Chrome Custom Tab," the default Web browser must be set to "Chrome".

Is there a way to determine which default web browser is being used on your device?

Answer (score 1):

you can check standard browser from app settings. this is for android 7 (german translation)

Settings -> Apps -> Chrome (App info, scroll down) -> Browser App -> Browser App (again)

Comment: Is there a way to check using Java Source Code in Android Studios?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611548